# How to download the source code of an Ubuntu package on a non Ubuntu machine?

Tags: repository, openssh, source-code

I need to tweak the code of OpenSSH-Server version 1.5.9 installed from the Ubuntu 12.04.05 (precise) main repository.

How do I download the source code of that package from the repos of that Ubuntu version without having access to an Ubuntu machine?

Comment: I've voted to reopen this. Asking where to obtain officially provided .deb files is not really a question about using an EoL release, even when the desired files are themselves provided for an EoL release. Also, and perhaps more compellingly, the [help/on-topic] says we allow questions about "Services provided by Ubuntu and Canonical." The official download servers -- even the old-releases server -- seem to me to qualify for that. This might benefit from another answer, but I don't see any reason to close it. (As for the idea that this is "not about Ubuntu": *what??*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the packages for all the current versions are kept at https://packages.ubuntu.com/ for downloading.

The [list for 12.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/allpackages) still exists but the [packages have been removed](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/openssh-server) (ubuntuupdates) so there is no 12.04 openssh server package available. The oldest available version is from 14.04. Or find an not-official source.

Comment: Is it known, why Canonical removed the packages. But also, do you know any non-official sources for the source of that package?

Comment: "End of life" means it gets deleted from the official repositories. Cost efficient to remove an OS that has become obsolete ;)  And no I do not. For open ssh it will be difficult. Old versions tend to get deleted. Here is a long list of mirriors https://www.openssh.com/portable.html but they are more likely to point to the newest version than an old one

Comment: Old packages and the source code is at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ . ... `openssh 1:5.9` →  `openssh_5.9p1-5ubuntu1.debian.tar.gz` → http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssh/